# Displaying values contained in an array

Tags: java, arrays, printing

I would like to display a message indicating if an input `value` is present in my `rollValue` array.

My code does't correctly identify such numbers.  This `search` method is what I have attempted, but why doesn't it display the correct message?

```
public void search(int value)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < rollValue.length; i++)
    {
        if (rollValue[i] == value)
        {        
            System.out.println(value + " was found");
        }            
        else
        {
            System.out.println(value + " was not found");
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to iterate (potentially) every value, before you can decide if it was found. Make two methods. Something like

```
private boolean hasValue(int value) {
    for (int roll : rollValue) {
        if (value == roll) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Then you can implement `search` by calling `hasValue` like

```
public void search(int value)
{
    if (hasValue(value)) 
    {        
        System.out.println(value + " was found");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println(value + " was not found");
    }
}
```

**or** as a one line [ternary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation) like

```
System.out.println(value + (hasValue(value) ? " was found" : " was not found"));
```

**or** you could add a short-circuit `return` in `search` and do something like

```
public void search(int value) {
    for (int roll : rollValue) {
        if (roll == value) {
            System.out.printf("%d was found%n", value);
            return;
        }
    }
    System.out.printf("%d was not found%n", value);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `for` loop is breaking after the first iteration. Move `break` inside the `if` used to find the value, maybe like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < rollValue.length; i++)
        {
            if (rollValue[i] == value)
            {        
                System.out.println(value + " was found");
               break;

            }

            else
            {
                System.out.println(value + " was not found");
            }
        }
```

Also you may not need to print the "was not found" string all the time so take it away.

Comment: This is what's happening with that code.  3 was found
2 was not found
2 was not found
2 was not found
2 was not found
2 was found

Comment: @MaxLawrence I knew this question is coming ;-) Just use a boolean flag with default value false. If item found, set the flag before breaking the loop. Outside loop, check flag and print accordingly.

Comment: Would the boolean be inside the for loop?

Comment: @MaxLawrence If i tell u everything you wouldn't be able to learn. So give it logical tries. More you struggle, longer will u remember stuff .Good luck!